# Phonegap / iOS - Unable to make inAppBrowser work

Tags: ios, cordova, inappbrowser

I've trying for some days to get inAppBrowser to work in a simple Phonegap App for iOS with no luck.

Nothing happens... No log con the console.log...

What I've done so far is:

- Install inAppBrowser using: `plugman --platform ios --project /path/to/app --plugin  inappbrowser`
- If I try to install it using 
  `phonegap plugin add
  https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git`
  it says it's already installed, so I assume installation is OK.
- Add the plugin call in the main config.xml file this way: `<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" version="0.2.4" />`

My index.html file looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>InAppBrowser Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for Cordova to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // Cordova is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
         var ref = window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  Hello World
  </body>
</html>
```

I understand, on launch, it should open the Apache home, or stay blank (because of Phonegap URL permissions), but it just shows up the "Hello World" text and nothing happens.

Any ideas of what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance, and sorry about my poor english!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the following in your config.xml:

I used to have org.apache.cordova.InAppBroweser - maybe from an older version and it caused issues.

Also make sure your config.xml (in your apk file) is created properly.